# FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, inputstream, filenotfoundexception, fileinputstream

Hi guys I'm new to java and one of my requirements is to create a program that will enable user to add edit delete view record such as employee, address, gender, status, days of work and  rate per day that is saved in a notepad , after adding that up the program will compute for the taxes and sss contribution etc that will be also save to a different txtfile and also can be view and edit. my problem is i cant write the computation on the txtfile and getting "FileNotFoundException". heres my code in reading and writting in the txt file

```
public static void payrollReadFromFile(String filename) {

        // initializes br identifer as BufferedReader.
        BufferedReader br = null;

        payrolls.clear(); // removes all elements in arraylist employees

        try {
            // instantiate br as FileReader with filename param
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename)); 
            try {

                 String name;               
                double   gincome, nincome, deduc, sss, pagibig, phil = 0; // initialize identifiers

                // reads each line through br identifier, and stores it on
                // temporary identifiers
                // loop continues until null is encountered
            while ((name = br.readLine()) != null) {

                    gincome = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
                    sss = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
                    pagibig = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
                    phil = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
                    deduc = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
                    nincome = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());                    

                    // adds the data to employees arraylist
                    payrolls.add(new Person( name, gincome, sss, pagibig, phil,deduc, nincome));
                }
            } finally {
                br.close(); // closes BufferedReader
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



    // method which writes data into parameter 'filename'
    // uses PrintWriter and FileWriter
    public static boolean payrollWriteToFile(String filename) {
        boolean saved = false;
        PrintWriter pw = null; // pw is a PrintWriter identifier

        try {
            // instantiate pw as PrintWriter, FileWriter
            pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(filename)); 

            try {

                // for each loop. each data from employees is written to parameter
                // filename
                for (Person payroll : payrolls) {
                                       // pw.println(employee.getId());
                    pw.println(payroll.getName());
                    pw.println(payroll.getGincome());
                    pw.println(payroll.getSss());
                    pw.println(payroll.getPagibig());
                    pw.println(payroll.getPhil());
                    pw.println(payroll.getDeduc());
                    pw.println(payroll.getNincome());


                }
                saved = true;
            } finally {
                pw.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return saved;
    }
```

can someone help me? i dont know what to do. thanks in advance

Comment: FileNotFound, is exactly that, you are trying to open a file that is not there.

Comment: help me pls you can email me @ jmtabasa@gmail.com

Comment: Are you sure your file is in the correct place? `System.getProperty("user.dir");` will tell you the current directory of your program while you're running it.

Comment: .. i just copy what i did in creating a file with my employees .. coz i want to have seperate txt file for employees record and payroll.. I've been working on this since afternoon can you help me?

Comment: What are you passing as argument (what is the value of filename) and where is the file on your disk?

Comment: FileNotFoundException simply means that file does not present at given path..!! Create the file and run the program again.

Comment: @user2014814, we're trying to help you, but you have to help us help you by answering our questions.

Comment: @RaptorDotCpp what do you mean by " the value of the filename" 
after running the program supposedly it will automatically create payroll.txt but it didint create it in my workspace

Comment: @SaurabhAgarwal Id tried to create the payroll.txt file in my workspace . yes the error has gone but the problem now is the computed value was not written in there.

Comment: When you call `payrollReadFromFile`, what is your parameter. For example: in `payrollReadFromFile("file.txt")`, the value of filename is "file.txt".

Comment: @SaurabhAgarwal thus i cannot view the record Sorry guys for my stupidity i am really new in java.

Comment: @RaptorDotCpp what i did there is payrollReadFromFile("payroll.txt")

Comment: You must always check for null after using the readLine function.

Comment: @SaurabhAgarwal i have this code BufferedReader br = null;

Comment: gincome = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine()); This in not a good practice while working with readers.

Comment: @SaurabhAgarwal why is that?

Comment: Bcoz it may give you NullPointerException if br.readLine() don't read any thing.

Comment: @SaurabhAgarwal i got that before but i have that fixed..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nice thing about exceptions is that the stack trace (which is probably what you are seeing in your console output) tells you exactly which line of code threw the exception. Most likely it was this line:

```
br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
```

Look at the code that passes the file to your `payrollReadFromFile` method. The file you are passing is not where you think it is. It might make more sense to pass a File object instead of String since the File object contains not just the name of the file but the complete path to that File as well.

Comment: The FileNotFoundException has gone my problem now is writing  in the txt file. i cant wirte to it

Comment: I used PrintWriter and FileWriter..

my code is:

PrintWriter pw = null;
 pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(filename));

Comment: Your question was voted down because it was not exactly clear what your issue was. Try asking a new question and be clear on exactly what your error is and what you have tried.There is nothing wrong with the one line of code in your comment. Help us understand what you are trying to do and what your error is (and of course post the relevent code) and I or someone else will answer it.

Answer (score 0):

The key to this question and answer is that the level of code, and the level of question are quite different.  It seems to me that this code was written by someone with a decent amount of java knowledge, but the person asking (by their own admission) is a novice.  So the choices are two:

1)  Hire one of us to fix it for you.  You can hire me, but I am expensive, there are others that will do it on the cheap.

2)  Learn Java, if you are student taking a class, then you should be learning this.  Break it down take it slow.

Here is a debugging tip:

System.out.println(filename);

This way you can see what the filename you are looking for is.

It is not the responsibilty of stackoverflow contributers to fix your problems.  We are here to help you learn.

Answer (score -1):

You can throw exceptions, like this:

```
public static void payrollReadFromFile(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException {
```

Also I suggest you look up the try and catch method.

Comment: How does this help them? They're already using try-catch and the problem is that the file is not found, not that they don't know what a FileNotfoundException is.

Comment: This can't help him out..!!